# При повторном запуске кода в другом потоке double-linked list corruption

Tags: c++, linux, многопоточность, память, динамические-массивы

Есть сервер, который принимает подключения от терминалов, и выбрасывает их в отдельный поток. Перед созданием потока я проверяю глобальный контейнер на наличие подключений с данным терминалом. При завершении потока - из контейнера оная запись удаляется.

Теперь собственно об ошибке: когда я подключаюсь в первый раз - проблем не возникает, могу обмениваться пакетами до посинения. Если я подключусь второй раз от имени этого терминала - получаю ошибку.

Могу при этом параллельно ещё от имени надцати терминалов параллельно подключиться - всё ок. Но если хоть один из них я отключу (отключение происходит нормально, очистка контейнера происходит с результатом в 1 - ключ был уникален).

Листинги:

1) Функция приёма пакета, собственно в которой я крашусь.

```
/*
 * @is_terminal_commands    true, if we expecting terminal's commands, false - if platforms.
 * @ ret                    0 if real package length don't matches with length from package
 *                          -1 if socket error
 *                          -2 if got unexpected command
 */
int getPackage(ClockConnection *connection, package *ret, bool is_terminal_commands = false){
    memset(ret->CS,'\0',2);
    memset(ret->imay,'\0',10);
    memset(ret->len,'0',5);// inserting zeros.
    memset(ret->command,'\0',10);
    ret->have_args = false;

    memset(buffer, '\0', size);

    int recv_bytes = 0;
    int multiplier = 0;

    struct timeval t;    // устанавливаем время ожидания в 1 сек.
    t.tv_sec = 1;
    t.tv_usec = 0;
    fd_set s;
    int select_res;

    /*
     * waiting for package
     */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(connection->mutex));

    do{
        FD_ZERO(&s);
        FD_SET(connection->tcp_socket, &s);
        select_res = select((connection->tcp_socket)+1,&s, nullptr, nullptr, &t);
        if(select_res < 0){
            puts("socket error, while waited for data");
            return -1;
        }else if(select_res > 0){
            break;
        }
        t.tv_sec = 1;
        t.tv_usec = 0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(connection->mutex));
        sleep(2);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(connection->mutex));
    }while( select_res == 0);

    /* reading package to buffer.
     * if buffer too small and the package cannot be readen,
     * size of buffer increasing on opt_buffer, up to package will be readen
     */
    int size = 1;// if I'll set big size (for example 1100)
    char *buffer = new char[size];// then memory corrupt will here. (on second time, when terminal will open second connection (previous - closed : 100%)
    do{
        multiplier++;
        try{
            delete[] buffer;
            size = opt_buffer*multiplier;
            buffer = new char[size];// here is double-linked list corrupted
            memset(buffer, '\0', size);
        }catch(std::exception & e){
            puts("sth going wrong");
        }

        recv_bytes = recv( connection->tcp_socket, buffer, opt_buffer * multiplier - 1, 0 | MSG_PEEK);
        if(recv_bytes == 0 || recv_bytes < 0) return -1;
    }while( strchr( buffer, (int)']') == nullptr);


    std::string result(buffer);


    if(recv_bytes < 0){
        ret->good = false;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(connection->mutex));
        delete[] buffer;
        return -1;
    }



    result = result.substr( 0, result.find_first_of(']')+1 )+'\n';

    if(result.find_first_of(',') != string::npos) {
        puts("arguments detected");
        ret->have_args = true;
        delete[] ret->arguments;
        ret->arguments = new char[recv_bytes];
    }
    if ( opt_debug > 0 ) {
        printf("\nReceived %d bytes on socket.\n%s\n",recv_bytes, result.c_str());
    }
    int res = sscanf(result.c_str(), "[%[^*]*%[^*]*%[^*]*%[^],],%[^]]", ret->CS, ret->imay, ret->len, ret->command, ret->arguments);

    if( res < 4){

        pthread_mutex_lock(&stat_mutex);
        fprintf(statistics, "Bad data in sock %d. Waiting while send again...", connection->tcp_socket);
        printf("Bad data in sock %d. Source data: %s", connection->tcp_socket, result.c_str());
        printf("Parsed:\n CS:%s\n imay:%s\n len:%s\n command:%s\n", ret->CS,ret->imay,ret->len,ret->command);
        fprintf(statistics,"Parsed:\n CS:%s\n imay:%s\n len:%s\n command:%s\n", ret->CS,ret->imay,ret->len,ret->command);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&stat_mutex);

        ret->good = false;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(connection->mutex));
        delete[] buffer;
        return -1;
    }

    unsigned int len_int = stoul(ret->len, nullptr, 16);

    /* len in package means length of package, after last '*' until ']',
     * so to check full length of package, need to include another parts
     * 2 bytes for CS,
     * 2 for '['
     * 10 for imay,
     * 4 for len,
     * 3 for '*'
     */
    ret->pack_leng = result.length() - 1;
    if( ret->pack_leng != len_int + 21 ){
        printf("sizes don't match. ret->pack_leng = %d. len_int=%d", ret->pack_leng,len_int);
        recv( connection->tcp_socket, buffer, recv_bytes, 0 );

        ret->good = false;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(connection->mutex));
        delete[] buffer;
        return 0;
    }

    bool terminal_command = false, platform_command = false;
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < const_arr_length(terminal_commands); i++){
        if( strcmp(ret->command, terminal_commands[i].c_str()) == 0 ){
            terminal_command =  true;
        }
    }

    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < const_arr_length(platform_commands); i++){
        if( strcmp(ret->command, platform_commands[i].c_str()) == 0 ){
            platform_command = true;
        }
    }

    if( terminal_command == platform_command){
        //pizdec... or unknown (unhandled) command
        ret->good = false;
        recv( connection->tcp_socket, buffer, recv_bytes, 0 );
        puts("pizdec");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(connection->mutex));
        delete[] buffer;
        return -2;
    }
    if( (is_terminal_commands && !terminal_command) || (!is_terminal_commands && terminal_command)){
        // unexpected command
        ret->good = true;
        puts("unexpected_command");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(connection->mutex));
        delete[] buffer;
        return -2;
    }


    puts("attempt to write statistics");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&stat_mutex);
        fprintf(statistics,"from %s in %.6f sec.: %s\n",
                inet_ntoa(client_address.sin_addr),
                time_to_seconds( &time_start, &time_now ),
                result.c_str());

        if ( fflush(statistics) != 0 ) {
            if ( opt_debug > 0 ) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot flush buffers: %s\n", strerror(errno) );
            }
            else {
                syslog( LOG_DAEMON | LOG_CRIT, "Cannot flush buffers: %s", strerror(errno) );
            }
        }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&stat_mutex);

    ret->good = true;
    recv( connection->tcp_socket, buffer, recv_bytes, 0 );
    delete[] buffer;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(connection->mutex));
    return recv_bytes;
}
```

Опрос функции циклично производится в теле функции, которую выбрасывает главным потоком в дочерний. При разрыве соединения цикл завершается, и я чищу буферы, в том числе и контейнер (вроде бы, едиственный двусвязный список, который мне вообще пришлось использовать...)

```
while ( (recv_bytes = getPackage( connection, &pkg, true )) > -2 ) { // and reading socket
// analysing
}
```

2) Удаление подключения из контейнера `unordered_map<long long, ClockConnection>`

```
if(connections.connections.erase((long long)arg_imay) != 1){
                printf("somehow connection with %lld wasn't erased from container", arg_imay);
            }else{
                printf("connection with %lld was erased from container", arg_imay);
            }
```

В проекте сравнительно много кода, что бы публиковать всё. Если этого мало - я выложу архив с workspace'ом. Пишу из-под ubuntu под eclipse kepler.

Список `connection`'ов я правлю под отдельным, глобальным мьютексом. Контейнер я правлю в двух местах - вставка елемента перед выбрасыванием потока, и удаление елемента перед завершением потока. Оба случая происходят с захваченным мьютексом.

Comment: Первая идея — у вас `connection->mutex` у каждого соединения свой, а список `connection`'ов общий. Под каким `mutex`'ом вы правите список `connection`'ов?

Comment: @VladD извините, что не отвечал - возникли проблемы с переносом аккаунта на русский стэк. 
Контейнер с соединениями я правил под отдельным мьютексом.

За это время я решил проблему - программа крашилась не там, где показывал дебаг (почему так получалось - тоже вопрос...), и решение моё не хорошее - пришлось отказаться от динамической памяти. Сейчас я оформлю апдейт с подробным описанием.

Comment: @VladD, я попробовал повторить баг, и внезапно не смог его отловить... Поэтому, работающий код я представил в качестве ответа - если интересно - смотрите. Буду рад услышать критику (всё же, я только начинаю заниматься чем-то интересным на С++).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как показало раскапывание проблемы, ошибка возникала совсем в другом месте, а не там где показывала среда. Причина крылась в использовании динамической памяти, а вот ПОЧЕМУ это вызывало ошибку - я не понимаю. 
Если говорить прямо - вчера этот код вызывал краш. По всей функции я комментировал использование переменной, и просто удалял в конце.
Пробовал освобождать память сразу после выделения - помогало. Если же я делаю это спустя 100 строк (не используя её) - ловлю краш. 
Сейчас же всё работает. Магия, ёлки...
Итого имеем работающий код:

```
void parse_position_data(const char *arg_pos_data, position_data *pdata){
    pdata->reset_dynamic();// reseting buffer

    //fetching data
    sscanf(arg_pos_data, "%*c%*c%*c%*c%*c%*c,%*c%*c%*c%*c%*c%*c,%*c,%*f,%*c,%*f,%*c,%*f,%*f,%*f,%*d,%*d,%*d,%*d,%*d,%*d,%d",&pdata->base_stations_quantity);
    pdata->nearby = new base_station_opt[pdata->base_stations_quantity];
    char day[3], month[3], year[3], hour[3], min[3], sec[3];
    memset(day, '\0', 3);
    memset(month, '\0', 3);
    memset(year, '\0', 3);
    memset(hour, '\0', 3);
    memset(min, '\0', 3);
    memset(sec, '\0', 3);
    char *pos_data = new char[opt_buffer];

    sscanf(arg_pos_data, "%c%c%c%c%c%c,%c%c%c%c%c%c,%c,%f,%c,%f,%c,%f,%f,%f,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%ld,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%s",
            &day[0], &day[1], &month[0], &month[1], &year[0], &year[1],
            &hour[0], &hour[1], &min[0], &min[1], &sec[0], &sec[1],
            &pdata->positioning,
            &pdata->latitude,
            &pdata->mark_latit,
            &pdata->longitude,
            &pdata->mark_longit,
            &pdata->speed,
            &pdata->direction,
            &pdata->altitude,
            &pdata->satel_num,
            &pdata->signal_intensity,
            &pdata->power,
            &pdata->steps_num,
            &pdata->roll_num,
            &pdata->terminal_state,
            &pdata->base_stations_quantity,
            &pdata->base_station_tower,
            &pdata->mcc_country_code,
            &pdata->mnc_netw_num,
            &pdata->base_station_area_code,
            &pdata->base_station_num,
            &pdata->base_station_signal_strength,
            pos_data
            );

    printf("pos_data:%s\n\n", pos_data);
    time_t timestamp;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time(&timestamp);
    timeinfo = localtime ( &timestamp );
    //parsed_data.date is ddmmyy string. 120115 = 12 january 2015.
    timeinfo->tm_year = atoi(year) + 100; // year from 1900
    timeinfo->tm_mon = atoi(month) - 1; // month since jan (0-11)
    timeinfo->tm_mday = atoi(day); // day of month (1-31)
    timeinfo->tm_hour = atoi(hour);
    timeinfo->tm_min = atoi(min);
    timeinfo->tm_sec = atoi(sec);
    pdata->timestamp = mktime(timeinfo);

    for(int i = 0; i < pdata->base_stations_quantity; i++){
        sscanf(pos_data, "%d,%d,%d,%s", &pdata->nearby[i].are_code, &pdata->nearby[i].number, &pdata->nearby[i].signal_strength, pos_data);
    }
    delete[] pos_data;
}
```

З,Ы, если есть за что - бейте по рукам, ибо это будет правильно, а мне только полезно.
З,З,Ы, надеюсь это кому-нибудь поможет. (И да - не верьте средам разработки, думайте головой сами. Среды писали люди, а они тоже ошибаются...)